# Better approach for event when tabitem is selected

Tags: c#, wpf, tabcontrol

I have a tabcontrol with 8 tabitems and many many datagrids and listbox inside them. 
I want to fire up an event only when one specific tabitem is selected.

The first approach is SelectionChanged in tabcontrol with an if statement inside it

```
If ((thetabiwant!=null)&& (thetabiwant.IsSelected)) 
{
//code here 
}
```

The second approach is to have a mouseup event in the desired tabitem.

What is the best approach?

(ups and downs is that SelectionChanged fires all the time because of the datagrids while the mouseup event solution doesn’t make me happy)

Thanks.

Comment: another approach is binding `SelectedItem` which would then be bound to the selected tab. But it is very context specific, close to opinion based. Without more context about your current solution it is hard to say what is "best". For instance, why would SelectionChanged be fired when other than a tab is selected?

Comment: all childs of tabcontrol including datagrids fires selectionchanged

Comment: Are you using MVVM ? If you do, are you using a specific MVVM framework ? If you do, which one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, you shouldn’t worry too much about fired events that you then skip because they don’t match your criteria. The framework itself does that *a lot*, and you will end up doing a lot of that too (for example when listening to `INotifyPropertyChanged` events).

In your case, the few additional `SelectionChanged` events that get fired are really negligible. Each event requires the user to actually change the tab, and that won’t happen to often. On the other hand, once you are in the tab you care for, there are actually a lot mouse events happening. Not that you need to care about the number of those either (you really shouldn’t unless you get problems) but of course you can avoid it.

So in this case, yes, just skipping the `SelectionChanged` event is the best approach.

Comment: Thanks.  I am just worrying too much. When the datagrids (that are inside the tabcontrol) change,they  fire the SelectionChanged of the tabcontrol , so it have more calls (maybe 70 per medium user interaction). Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You could also bind the IsSelected Property
In the set do what you need to do when it is changed to true

[TabItem.IsSelected](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.tabitem.isselected(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="0">
    <TabItem Header="One" IsSelected="{Binding Path=Tab1Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TabItem Header="Two" IsSelected="{Binding Path=Tab2Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
</TabControl>

private bool tab1Selected = true;
private bool tab2Selected = false;
public bool Tab1Selected
{
    get { return tab1Selected; }
    set
    {
        if (tab1Selected == value) return;
        tab1Selected = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Tab1Selected");
    }
}
public bool Tab2Selected
{
    get { return tab2Selected; }
    set
    {
        if (tab2Selected == value) return;
        tab2Selected = value;
        if (tab2Selected)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Tab2Selected");
            // do your stuff here
        }
        NotifyPropertyChanged("Tab2Selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: This does not answer the question. OP is not asking how to find out which tab is selected but what’s the best way to filter events only specific to one special tab.

Comment: @poke TabItem is a specific tab

Comment: It still doesn’t answer the question, whether to use the generic `TabChanged` event and then filter for the relevant tab, or use a tab-specific event (e.g. a mouse event) to recognize the tab.

Comment: @poke What part of this is a third option is not clear?  If you react to then TabItem.IsSelected the you don't filter at all.  The objective to recognize the  tab.  This does that directly.

Comment: `TabItem.IsSelected` is a *property*, not an event you can listen to. Also what “third option” are you talking about?

Comment: You can listen to a set.  See posted code.   As for "third option" - see first paragraph.

Comment: Okay, now I get what you mean. Thanks for the example. I wouldn’t encourage too much logic in the setter though as property getters/setters are supposed to be fast and long operations (or interupted ones) will freeze the UI.

Comment: @poke A long running event handler will also freeze the UI.